# Download page with javascript executed

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qtnetwork

I want to download a page with javascript executed using python. QT is one of solutions and here is the code:

```
class Downloader(QApplication):
  __event = threading.Event()

  def __init__(self):
    QApplication.__init__(self, [])
    self.webView = QWebView()
    self.webView.loadFinished.connect(self.loadFinished)

  def load(self, url):
    self.__event.clear()
    self.webView.load(QUrl(url))
    while not self.__event.wait(.05): self.processEvents()
    return self.webView.page().mainFrame().documentElement() if self.__ok else None

  def loadFinished(self, ok):
    self.__ok = ok
    self.__event.set()

downloader = Downloader()
page = downloader.load(url)
```

The problem is that sometimes `downloader.load()` return a page without javascript executed. `Downloader.loadStarted()` and `Downloader.loadFinished()` are called only once.
What is the proper way to wait for a complete page download?

**EDIT**

If add `self.webView.page().networkAccessManager().finished.connect(request_ended)` into `__init__()` and define

```
def request_ended(reply):
  print(reply.error(), reply.url().toString())
```

then it turns out that sometimes `reply.error()==QNetworkReply.UnknownNetworkError`. This behaviour stands when unreliable proxy is used, that fails to download some of the resources (part of which are js files), hence some of js not being executed. When proxy is not used (== connection is stable), every `reply.error()==QNetworkReply.NoError`.

So, the updated question is:

- Is it possible to retry getting `reply.request()` and apply it to the `self.webView`?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript requires a runtime to be executed with (python alone won't do) a popular one is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) these days.
Unfortuantely, PhantomJs has no python support anymore so you could resort to e.g. [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) to do this job for you which allows you to selectively execute JS you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)
It provides different WebDriver, for example, PhantomJS, or other common browsers, like firefox.